# C++ const reference

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
using trip_container = dummy_container;
using trip_const_reference = trip_container::const_reference;
```

When I change `trip_container` to some struct instead of `dummy_container`, I get an error in the second line with `::const_reference`:

> class "struct name" has no member "const_reference".

What is the problem?

Comment: The other mysterious "some struct" does not define a `const_reference` member?

Comment: how can i define it?

Comment: The same way you define any other member of any other class, in C++. There's nothing special about the name `const_reference`, it's just a name of a class member. See your C++ textbook for more information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To make a reference, append `&` to the name of the type (class/struct).

To make a `const` reference, prepend `const` to the name of the reference type.

```
using trip_container = some_struct;
using trip_reference = some_struct&;
using trip_const_reference = const some_struct&;
```

Actually, `const` can also go after the name of the type; some people like it better:

```
using trip_const_reference = some_struct const&;
```

---

As noted by Drew Dormann, "xxx_const_reference" is typically defined in container types, and it's a reference to elements of the container. So the declarations above are probably not what you want. You probably want something like this:

```
using trip_const_reference = const some_other_struct&;
```

where `some_struct` is a container which contains elements of type `some_other_struct`.

Comment: Typically, when a container defines `some_container::const_reference`, it is a reference to the contained type, not the container itself.